# What does "except null set" mean?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am watching a video on sufficient statistics [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9_lqHA6kU4&index=12&list=PLbMVogVj5nJRkNUH5v9qNEJvW7r2A7rEY).

In the video, the sufficient statistics is defined as follows. I am puzzled by the part in the ***red box***. I know it is describing some trivial situation, but I don't quite understand what this statement is talking about and how it is related to the definition of sufficient statistics. Thank you!

[image]

This screen capture is at about 5:00 of the video.

Comment: Null set is defined right after i.e. as $A$ being null means $P_\theta(A)=0.$ for all $\theta \in \Theta.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it said, a null set is just a set where $P_{\theta} (A)=0$ for all $\theta$. For a specific example, consider the uniform probability on $[0,1]$. Then the set $\{.5\}$ is a null set, as $P(.5)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I now understand what null set is, but I still don't get it why this "null set" statement conflicts with the definition and why it has to be mentioned.

Comment: It's saying essentially, "Such and such satisfies XYZ except on a really small portion of our space... so it's good enough."

Comment: @Squirtle Thanks for the comment. What I don't understand is how this "small portion" violates the definition. Is there a concrete example.

Comment: Quick answer:  Pretend that you never even saw the item you circled... just ignore it.  Longer answer: Take measure theory.  

The point is, a null set is a set of measure zero, and if you don't know what that is, just think of it as being "almost the empty set, but not".

Comment: I would say yeah, for the most part don't worry about the null set condition. Most definitions of sufficient statistic don't even include that condition.